# Cloud Firestore Document IDs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the document Ids from a /users collection. However, I don't see an id on the objects that are being returned. How do I get the document Ids for each document with my code listed below?

**Pages:**

1. AllUsers (Where I map all of the user objects to User components)
2. ViewUser (When the user component is clicked on, I want to use this document Id here)

**All Users Saga:**

```
let allUsersData = yield documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());
```

**Possibilities?**

- getId() (Where do I do this to add each id to each of the user objects?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `DocumentSnapshot` (like in your `documentSnapshots.docs`) has `id` and `data()`.

You're explicitly dropping the document IDs when you do this:

```
let allUsersData = yield documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());
```

To get both, stick to using `DocumentSnapshot` or (if you want to stick to plain old JSON objects) merge the id with the data:

```
documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => ({ id: document.id, ...document.data() }));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It appears to still giving me an error due to the ... and the {}. Am I missing something?

Comment: My code:     let users = yield documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => { id: document.id, ...document.data() });